# What is the appropriate design for a discrete choice experiment?

Tags: r, experiment-design, choice-modeling, orthogonal

I need to develop a discrete choice experiment in R, which is an unlabeled experiment.

However, after delving into the theory behind discrete choice experiments, it remains unclear whether there is a recommended design to employ. Although the orthogonal design appears to be a suitable choice, it becomes non-orthogonal once data is collected. Does this imply a need to transition to an efficient design? However, efficient designs necessitate prior estimates, which I currently lack. Considering my inclination towards using a MNL, I find myself leaning towards the orthogonal design.

I am perplexed about how to decide between the two. My choice set should consist of 2 options, each with the same 8 attributes having 2 levels (2^8 = 256 possible options). Each respondent should only evaluate one choice set due to time constraints in the survey. Consequently, blocking needs to be implemented.

Comment: There are not many specifics in your questions, what types of attributes, what is your response variable, what is the objective of the experiment, etc.  Yes, a fractional design would reduce the number runs needed.  Maybe a resolution III or IV design would work depending your objective and budget.